# downloading the eclipse java ee for application development

Tags: java, eclipse

i have one simple problem with downloading eclipse java ide for web application.I have to use struts2 and spring for my project.Before that for practise i want to execute some programs available in internet so that i can get idea on all the above things.

i am unable to download java ide ee..

how to download.

i have tried in internet but everytime it is going to eclipse site and showing the following link.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/r

when i click the link of java ee ide it is downloading one corrupt file of zip file.

can you please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 64 bit ->

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR2/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip

for 32 bit ->
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR2/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32.zip